# Problem with LED lamp PCB

Tags: led, pcb, mains, surface-mount, surge-protection

[image]

**Problems:**

*RED* – PCB trace gets blown up.

*PURPLE* – There seems to be some arcing from the live terminal to the resistor on the side, which results in a bridging that blows the traces between.

So far the problem occurred in 12 of 300 boards, all the same problems as above. It happens while in testing, which is made by a machine that toggles the lamps on and off for 10 seconds each.

The machine use contactors (50A) controlled by a micro-controller. Some MOVs (3x 20D431K and 1x 20D471K) were added to the outputs as counter measure, but the problem persists.

The PCB is an aluminum metal-core with copper traces. It’s rated for 50W 240V, with an onboard driver (that is what all the ICs are for, if needed I can give more information on it.)

Each lamp consists of a combination of the given board, so for example: a 200W lamp is made up of 4 boards connected in parallel.

I’ve been having this problem for some time now. Most of the time it is one board in a lamp that blows up.

So far,I’ve tried changing the testing machine entirely, adding MOVs and surge protectors to the inputs and outputs of the machine, tried different toggle frequency times, and redid the machine wiring, monitored for voltage spikes and surges, to no avail.

Other things that is worth mentioning: the voltage gets a little lower when testing a batch of lamps (usually between 8-12 lamps) around 206-210V, the problems happened on rainy/moist days, but no lightning happened while testing at all.

Comment: Without a schematic it is hard to say.  It could be that pc board contaminants left over after washing are creating a sneak path because the creepage distance is too short.  Does the problem every show up immediately when a new board is powered up for the first time, or is it always after some run time?  This could indicate thermal stress.

Comment: Those 200k resistors R1 and R2 looks awfully close to the unfused live connection.

Comment: You say no lighting? So testing in the dark?

Comment: `but no lighting happened while testing at all` ... did you mean to say `lightning`?

Comment: Sorry, I meant lightning strike, thunder, etc. Anything that could cause a large scale surge

Comment: @MrPivato - Hi, If you meant something different, please [edit] your question to change / update the text to correct / improve it. That is part of the philosophy of Stack Exchange - edit the question to improve it, as needed. Thanks.

Comment: A schematic would be most useful to fault find. I would use a variable power supply ( transformer ). You need to measure current drawn on power up. Are your using these outdoors? Condensation may be a problem..but need more info.

Comment: @MrPivato , you said "I’ve been having this problem for some time now. Most of the time it is one board in a lamp that blows up."  Do you mean that you also see this problem with customers, in production (out in the field)?

Comment: Are you able to add a schematic? This is liable to be highly useful.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes we don't have enough information to solve your problem. The next best thing, then, would be how to get more information.

So, my thoughts, in order, are...

1. Find a way to stop destroying the evidence (of what's really going on). First,
2. Measure the current during the 10-second high-current test, turning the test off before destruction occurs. Adding a sane current limit makes sense, and when the current is over 50% of normal (or whatever makes sense) then stop the test so that the short-circuit or other problem is still intact.  Then,
3. Find out what's going on by whatever means necessary, in my mind,
4. Measure component values and see if anything jumps out at you. If that doesn't work, then
5. Use an oscilloscope during shorter duration tests (that won't damage), to see if you can detect the problem that way. Next,
6. Remove everything from the board, (I use a heat gun, circular motion, keep probing LED's and chips until they come off)
7. Remove the solder resist with solvent, and
8. With sandpaper (by hand?), progressively remove material from the board to see if there are any manufacturing defects in the layers. May need a couple of boards for this.

At your next roadblock, post your next question.

In my mind, it's a short-circuit (manufacturing defect?).   But it could be a resonant mode you're not expecting.  It could also possibly be due to a particular combination of component tolerance variation.

Without a schematic, we can't just give you a fish -- we can only teach you how to catch your own slippery swimmer. Or nasty, crawling bug, as the case may be.

Good luck.

---

To show you what I mean, here's an example of a Before and After of trying to reverse a dollar store 100W bulb, where I followed some of the steps I suggested for you (this is an aluminum PCB, like yours):

Before heat gun:

[image]

After heat gun, and some razor-scraping:

[image]

It's four strings of 9 LED's, each string is 8 x 16V plus 1 x 8V.